# Pass data to variable in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller which gets the user to input a certain date (for an alarm) and I want this alarm to run when the app goes into background so I want to pass the NSDate into a variable in the App Delegate, what's the best way to do this?

I tried using this

```
 let appD = AppDelegate()
    appD.dat = dueDatePicker.date
```

but it didn't work out, once the user selects the date and hits save, the view controller segues to the main view controller,

heres the code I have running in the app delegate:

```
 var backgroundUpdateTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier!
   var dat:NSDate?
func beginBackgroundUpdateTask() {
    self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({
        self.endBackgroundUpdateTask()
    })
}

func endBackgroundUpdateTask() {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundUpdateTask)
    self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}

func doBackgroundTask() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        self.beginBackgroundUpdateTask()

        // Do something with the result.
        let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TaskModel", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
        let addTaskVC:AddTaskViewController = AddTaskViewController()


        println(self.dat)
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let comp = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: date)


        let seconds = Double(comp.second)
        println(seconds)
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(seconds, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().run()


        // End the background task.
        self.endBackgroundUpdateTask()
    })
}
```

My problem is that the variable dat keeps showing the value nil causing the app to crash as soon background mode is entered, any info is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create an instance of `AppDelegate`

in order to get your app delegate use that:

```
let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual syntax to refer to the AppDelegate instance is

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Never call initializers of classes having been designed (and instantiated) in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1) Init variable in AppDelegate.swift

ex:

```
var data:NSString!=""
```

2) create an AppDelegate instance in your viewcontroller

ex:

`let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate`

3) Pass your data by init value on appDelegate variable.

ex:

```
appDelegate.data="your_Sending_Data_to_AppDelegate"
```