# how to update the badge value during application loading?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

In my application i need to show the badge value depending on the cart items count and i had implemented the below lines in the view controller which i am getting the data using json and the badge value was not loading whenever the view controller was displayed and not updating the value  after delete and the badge value was not showing at start of the application as i am new to swift 3 i don't where to implement it can anyone help me how to clear the issue ?

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

 func downloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                //  print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Detail"))
            self.itemsArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Detail") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
                print(self.itemsArray.count)
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                    let key = "productPrice"
                    for array in self.itemsArray{
                        if let value = array[key] {
                            let cart = String(describing: value)
                            let endIndex = cart.index(cart.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)
                            let truncated = cart.substring(to: endIndex)
                            self.totalcartPrice.append(truncated)
                            print(self.totalcartPrice)
                            var sum = 0.00
                            for numbers in self.totalcartPrice{
                                sum += Double(numbers)!
                            }
                            print(sum)
                            self.increment = Int(sum)
                            self.total = String(sum) + "0KD"
                            let tabItems = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items as NSArray!
                            let tabItem = tabItems?[1] as! UITabBarItem
                            self.appDelegate.badgeValue = String(Int(self.itemsArray.count))
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
func deleteButtonAction(button : UIButton) {
        let buttonPosition = button.convert(CGPoint(), to: tableDetails)
        let index = tableDetails.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
        self.itemsArray.remove(at: (index?.row)!)
        self.tableDetails.deleteRows(at: [index!], with: .automatic)
        tableDetails.reloadData()
        let tabItems = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items as NSArray!
        let tabItem = tabItems?[1] as! UITabBarItem
        self.appDelegate.badgeValue = String(Int(self.itemsArray.count))
        if (tableView(tableDetails, numberOfRowsInSection: 0) == 0){
            tableDetails.isHidden = true
            emptyView.isHidden = false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rootViewController to update badge from AppDelegate. Like this

```
let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as!UITabBarController! 
let tabArray = rootViewController?.tabBar.items as NSArray! 
let tabItem = tabArray.objectAtIndex(1) as! UITabBarItem 
tabItem.badgeValue = "34"
```

Comment: how to pass the value to that class ?

Comment: you can try this for passing value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049924/passing-data-from-app-delegate-to-view-controller

Comment: this link is for passing data from app delegate to view controller but here i need to send the data from view controller to app delegate is this the same process i need to used ? @Vinod Kumar

Comment: passing data from viewcontroller 
 to app delegate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124728/pass-data-to-variable-in-appdelegate

Comment: you can also create a variable in appdelegate then get app delegate object into view controller then set value in aap delegate variable @user

Comment: i tried creating a variable and passing data from app delegate object into view controller but the data was not passed @Vinod Kumar

Comment: this is the code for app delegate class  var badgeValue: String?
 let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as!UITabBarController!
        let tabArray = rootViewController?.tabBar.items as NSArray!
        let tabItem = tabArray?.object(at: 1) as! UITabBarItem
        tabItem.badgeValue = badgeValue

Comment: and in view controller class let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 self.appDelegate.badgeValue = String(Int(self.itemsArray.count))

Comment: i had added my complete code please check and help me bro

Comment: var value = 0
this variable  in app delegate  and below code in view controller resultent it is updated

 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 appDelegate.value =  5
 print(appDelegate.value)

if you want to update badge in app delegate then use local notification or custom delegate@user

Comment: how to use local notification ? @Vinod kumar

Comment: NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(self.getMyProfile),name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue:"UpdateProfileNotification"),object: nil)

above code set in app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

and put below method in app delegate 

 func getMyProfile()
    {
}

below code put into view controller

  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("UpdateProfileNotification"), object: nil)

Comment: but how to pass the data here in this ? @VinodKumar

Comment: you can pass data  as 

let imageDataDict:[String: UIImage] = ["image": image]

  // post a notification
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notificationName"), object: nil, userInfo: imageDataDict)

Comment: you can send value in user info and also get from notification.userinfo

Comment: got bro @Vinod Kumar

Comment: great bro @user